# I can't use Process in a function

Tags: swift, process

I have a problem I would like to use the function `Process()` but when I call it in a function I get

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Process'

But when I call it directly in my code it works.
Someone knows why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. Minimal, complete, verifiable example applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Please provide your tired code

Answer (score 1):

As you neither mentioned which Platform you are targeting to nor provided any kind of code, you'll need to take note of the following things:

1. `Process()` was renamed to `CommandLine()` in Swift 3.0
2. If you are targeting iOS, `CommandLine()` isn't available, so you'll need to do the following:

#### Using NSTask() on iOS:

The best way to achieve this, or at least the one I prefer the most (also I didn't find any other way to do this), is to use a [custom Objective-C header file](https://pastebin.com/V28wJq6A) which creates the object `NSTask()` and everything it needs.

Then, in order to use this code with Swift, you'll need to create a [Bridging-Header](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift), in which you'll need to import the `NSTask.h` for it to be exposed to Swift and being able to use it in your Swift code.

Once done this, just use the following function in your code whenever you want to run a task:

```
func task(launchPath: String, arguments: String...) -> NSString {
    let task = NSTask.init()
    task?.setLaunchPath(launchPath)
    task?.arguments = arguments

    // Create a Pipe and make the task
    // put all the output there
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task?.standardOutput = pipe

    // Launch the task
    task?.launch()
    task?.waitUntilExit()

    // Get the data
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    return output!
}
```

And call it like this:

```
task(launchPath: "/usr/bin/echo", arguments: "Hello World")
```

This will also return the value, so you can even display it by doing:

```
print(task(launchPath: "/usr/bin/echo", arguments: "Hello, World!"))
```

Which will print:

```
~> Hello, World!
```

For this to work and not throwing an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, you'll need to set the launchPath to the executable's full path instead to just the directory containing it.

You'll also need to set all the command arguments separated by ***commas***.

Tested on both iPad Mini 2 (*iOS 12.1 ~> Jailbroken*) and iPhone Xr (*iOS 12.2 ~> not jailbroken*).

**NOTE**: Even though this works both on non-jailbroken and jailbroken devices, your App will be rejected on the AppStore, as [@ClausJørgensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95309/claus-j%C3%B8rgensen) said:

> You're using private APIs, so it'll be rejected on the App Store. Also, Xcode 11 has some new functionality that will trigger a build failure when using certain private APIs.

I'd only recommend the usage of this for apps that won't be uploaded to the App Store, otherwise, try to achieve what you want without using commands, there sure will be any other way to do that.

If your app is targeting jailbroken iOS devices and will be uploaded to a third-party store like Cydia, Zebra, Thunderbolt or Sileo, then this would work correctly.